# Shoutem eslit 'define' is not defined no-undef

Tags: shoutem

He Guys

I am using shoutem with a react-native webpack 4 project i i get the following error...

```
./src/node_modules/MyProject/boilerplate/node_modules/tinycolor2/tinycolor.js
  Line 1187:  'define' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 1188:  'define' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

I believe it has something to do with AMD and CommonJS but when i try to turn either off n WebPack i get the same issues.

Does anyone have any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

add :

```
"env": {
  "amd": true
}
```

in your eslintrc file.